# Video will not display in bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a bootstrap theme that I am trying to get working.  It displays a video in the background but also defaults to an image if that does not work.  I can get the images to show but cannot get it to link up to the video.  I have googled this and cruised are SO for a while and have not been able to solve the problem.

In the original code it had this linking to the images and same for the video

```
 <img alt="" src="assets/img/icon1.png">
```

which I had to change to the following in order to get it to work

```
 <%= image_tag "icon1.png" %>
```

the video tag is in the javascript and looks like this

```
<!-- Initialize background video in hero section, (above the fold) -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#videohero").wallpaper({
            source: {
                mp4:    "video/hero.mp4",
                ogg:    "video/hero.ogv",
                webm:   "video/hero.webm"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

so it is linking to "hero.mp4"

so I get the same error on this video as I do when I had the "img src= " code in there where it says routing error no route matches GET (asset path here).  so what I am looking for specifically is how do I change the code above so that it will link to the video  I tried this but it did not work.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#videohero").wallpaper({
            source: {('<%= video_tag 'hero.mp4' %>')

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I also tried this

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#videohero").wallpaper({
            source: {
                mp4:  ('<%= video_tag  "video/hero.mp4" %>'),
                ogg:    "video/hero.ogv",
                webm:   "video/hero.webm"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I just am not sure how to write this in javascript and cannot find it online anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Ruby developer, but I'll try to help you. I'd write a comment, but it's too much content to a comment.

The `video_tag` function that you're trying to use as `<%= video_tag 'hero.mp4' %>` returns the output `<video src="/videos/hero.mp4" />`, according to the documentation.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

What I think you are trying to do is get the **source** for the image, not the entire tag. For it you can use the `video_path` function, according to the documentation.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html